# Пропадает анимация после оборачивания ImageView в ещё один LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-fragment, анимация

Я использую анимацию для *Shared Elements* при переходе из одного фрагмента на второй, анимируя при этом один `ImageView`. И всё работает. Но когда я оборачиваю этот `ImageView` во втором фрагменте в ещё один `LinearLayout`:

```
               <LinearLayout
                    android:transitionName="@string/image_transition"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_city_image"
                        android:transitionName="@string/image_transition"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:scaleType="matrix"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/content_descr_city_image" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

анимация пропадает. Почему это происходит?

Вот что было раньше:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и так раньше выглядел весь макет второго фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_city_image"
                    android:transitionName="@string/image_transition"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="matrix"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/content_descr_city_image" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@drawable/header_background"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_city_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        tools:text="@tools:sample/cities" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        tools:text="@tools:sample/cities" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_weather"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:text="@tools:sample/cities"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

и как стало после оборачивания `ImageView` в ещё один `LinearLayout`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде LinearLayout не нужен `android:transitionName="@string/image_transition"`.

Comment: Вы правы, не заметила этого) Спасибо!